# How to calculate when video is finished

Tags: javascript, video

I'm creating a rewards site where people can watch videos to earn points. The problem is that people will skip to the end of the video to earn their points. Therefore, I need to track when the video is done by a timer.

I have the following code:

```
var video_percent_count = 0;

function video_percent() {

  var prize_video = document.getElementById("prize_video");
  total_duration = Math.floor(prize_video.duration) + 1;

  video_percent_count++;
  percent = =total_duration / video_percent_count;
  alert(percent);
}
```

To summarize, the code is adding to a variable every second, this is the timer. The function then grabs the total duration, then divides it by the timer for a percentage.

**The function is not outputting a proper percentage, why is this code incorrect?**

Comment: percent = =total_duration / video_percent_count; Two = signs?

Comment: Can you show the call that calls this function every second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a syntax error:

```
percent = =total_duration / video_percent_count;
```

Should be:

```
percent = total_duration / video_percent_count;
```

Notice the second `=` is removed.

In the future, you can use the web console to find simple syntax errors such as this one.

Comment: I actually copied the code incorrectly inside the SO editor, but you solved the problem correctly based on what I posted. I found a solution regardless...